# Reorder bars with percentages using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

[image]I am trying to order the bars in descending order according to the frequency (y axis) of the blue area (1 in the legend).

Here is a dummy data and my attempt.

Thank you for you help!

```
library(ggplot2)

Region <- c('A','B','C', 'D', 'E')
Factor <- c(1, 0)
Freq <- c(0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5)
Value <- c(100, 250, 30, 300, 120, 50, 400, 90, 150, 320)

d <- data.frame(Region, Factor, Freq, Value)

d$Factor <- factor(d$Factor)

ggplot(d, aes(x= reorder(Region, -Freq), y= Freq, fill = Factor)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "blue"))+
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
ylab("%") +
xlab(" ") +
theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
geom_text(aes(label = Value), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color 
= "white", check_overlap = T, size = 3) +
coord_flip() +
guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=T))
```

Update:
The answer showed in the "duplicate" question does not work.
The answer showed in this post [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph/9231857#9231857) seems to do not work.

Comment: Use `reorder` to order the levels of your factor [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9231857/903061).

Comment: It doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: @Julia why it doesn't work? What have you done and what error message did you get?

Comment: @Julia please update the question

Comment: ggplot(d, aes(x= reorder(Region, -Freq, function(x) - length(x)), y= Freq, fill = Factor)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "blue"))+
  ylab("%") +
  xlab(" ") +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  geom_text(aes(label = Value), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color = "white",
            check_overlap = T, size = 3) +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=T)) -- It does not change the order of the bars, no error

Comment: Well, you do have to reorder by the values that determine the ordering. You want to reorder by the `Freq` column when `Factor` is `'1'`, so `d$freq_1 = with(d, ifelse(Factor == '1', Freq, NA))`, then 
`d$Region = reorder(d$Region, d$freq_1, FUN = mean, na.rm = T)`, and your plot will work fine.

Comment: Alternatively,along the lines of the last part of [Gavin's answer at the dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5210833/903061), you could just pull out the levels in the right order and refactor: `s = d[d$Factor == '1', ]`, then `levs = s$Region[order(s$blue_freq)]`, and `d$Region =  factor(d$Region, levels = levs)`.

Comment: @Gregor2 That worked. Thanks!